# How to to create unique random integer ID for primary key for table?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

I was wondering if anybody knew a good way to create a unique random integer id for a primary key for a table. I'm using MySQL. The value has to be integer.

Comment: why not just `AUTO_INCREMENT` ?

Comment: Because I want to use that value to Encode to Base62 and then use that for an id in a url.  If i auto increment, it might be obvious to the user how the url id is generated.

Comment: To get around your issue of security, you could use AUTO_INCREMENT and include a randomly created number as a field. To get your userid, you take the AUTO id + that random number. Run it through a hash (SHA128 will work just fine). Even if the random number is the same (which it realistically won't be), combining it with another number then SHA'ing it will give you your userid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your're open to suggestions and you can implement it, use UUIDs.
MySQL's `UUID()` function will return a 36 chars value which can be used for `ID`.

If you want to use integer, still, I think you need to create a function `getRandID()` that you will use in the `INSERT` statement. This function needs to use random + check of existing ids to return one that is not used before.

Check `RAND()` function for MySQL.

Comment: How do you make sure the random value is not being used by another person at the same time.  For example person A and B get the same random number.  Both check at the same time if it exists, it doesn't so they both insert.  Of course, one fails because of the primary key constraint.  What do you do, to go around that? Locking tables?  Never used it and kind of uneasy of using it.

Comment: Thats the beauty of UUID (Universal unique identifier). Quoting Wikipedia: "The intent of UUIDs is to enable distributed systems to uniquely identify information without significant central coordination. Thus, anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with reasonable confidence that the identifier will never be unintentionally used by anyone for anything else. Information labeled with UUIDs can therefore be later combined into a single database without needing to resolve name conflicts."

Comment: @Tesh I would just repeat the function in the CATCH when an exception arose due to the UNIQUE constraint and continue until you are able to insert a row with that random Id.

Answer (score 14):

**In response to:** *"Because I want to use that value to Encode to Base62 and then use that for an id in a url. If i auto increment, it might be obvious to the user how the url id is generated."*

If security is your aim then using Base62, even with a "randomly" generated number won't help.

A better option would:

- Do not re-invent the wheel -- use `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- Then use a cryptographic hash function + a randomly generated string (hidden in the db for that particular url) to generate the final "unique id for that url"

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Okay I use auto increment and then use a cryptographic hash function + a randomly generated string.  But I need my url to be short.  Short like how tinyurl does it.  By using cryptographic won't I get a "unique id for that url" that is long?

Answer (score 7):

How you generate the unique_ids is a useful question - but you seem to be making a counter productive assumption about *when* you generate them!

My point is that you do not need to generate these unique id's at the time of creating your rows, because they are essentially independent of the data being inserted.

What I do is pre-generate unique id's for future use, that way I can take my own sweet time and absolutely guarantee they are unique, and there's no processing to be done at the time of the insert.

For example I have an orders table with order_id in it.  This id is generated on the fly when the user enters the order, incrementally 1,2,3 etc forever.  The user does not need to see this internal id.

Then I have another table - unique_ids with (order_id, unique_id).  I have a routine that runs every night which pre-loads this table with enough unique_id rows to more than cover the orders that might be inserted in the next 24 hours.  (If I ever get 10000 orders in one day I'll have a problem - but that would be a good problem to have!)

This approach guarantees uniqueness and takes any processing load away from the insert transaction and into the batch routine, where it does not affect the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` for your table, but give the users the encrypted version:

encrypted_id: `SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(id, 'my-private-key'));`

id: `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(encrypted_id), 'my-private-key');`

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach (`PHP` and `MySQL`):

---

**Short**

1. Generate random `number` for `user_id (UNIQUE)`
2. Insert row with generated `number` as `user_id`
3. If inserted row count equal to 0, go to point 1

Looks heavy? Continue to read.

---

**Long**:

Table:

```
users (user_id int UNIQUE)
```

Code:

```
<?php
// values stored in configuration
$min = 1;
$max = 1000000;

$numberOfLoops = 0;
do {
    $randomNumber = rand($min, $max);

    // the very insert
    $insertedRows = insert_to_table(
        'INSERT INTO foo_table (user_id) VALUES (:number)', 
        array(
            ':number' => $randomNumber
        ));

    $numberOfLoops++;

    // the magic
    if (!isset($reported) && $numberOfLoops / 10 > 0.5) {
        /**
         * We can assume that at least 50% of numbers
         * are already in use, so increment values of
         * $min and $max in configuration.
         */
        report_this_fact();
        $reported = true;
} while ($insertedRows < 1);
```

---

1. All values (`$min`, `$max`, `0.5`) are just for explanation and they have no statistical meaning.
2. Functions `insert_to_table` and `report_this_fact` are not build in PHP. The are also as numbers just for clarify of explanation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature. I would use that.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) more examples.

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is going to be your best bet for this.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) are some examples.

If you need to you can adjust where the increment value starts (by default it's 1).

Answer (score 0):

my way, for both 32bit and 64bit platform.  result is 64bit

```
function hexstr2decstr($hexstr){
    $bigint = gmp_init($hexstr, 16);
    $bigint_string = gmp_strval($bigint);
    return $bigint_string;
}

function generate_64bitid(){
    return substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 16, 16);
}

function dbGetUniqueXXXId(){
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $decstr = hexstr2decstr(generate_64bitid());

        //check duplicate for mysql.tablexxx
        if($dup == false){
            return $decstr;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, don't use AUTO_INCREMENT if you don't want to.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `demotable` (
    `MyKey` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT floor(rand() * 1000000),'utf8_general_ci',
    `MyValue` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`MyUUID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

It creates a primary key MyKey and the default value for it is an expression that is a random integer.

See yourself, it creates a new random key when you add a value like his:

```
INSERT INTO demotable(MyValue) VALUES(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others also mentioned, UUID is a powerful tool for what you expect.

But you can do a small modification so that you won't have to assign it yourself every time (the same way as "AUTOINCREMENT"):

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT UUID()
)
```

But it still has a downside: It occupies a lot of storage. If your database is small then it is ok, otherwise, you can consider converting it to binary using mysql's built-in functions (mysql 8.0+). It occupies less storage.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())
)
```

And read from it this way:

```sql
SELECT 
  BIN_TO_UUID(id) id 
FROM users
```