# How a unique id should be generated randomly or autoincrement

Tags: php

I am generating a unique id auto increment. Is it good? Or should I generate it randomly?
which one is better and why?

Comment: I don't know if there is a best practice in that. For maintenance reason, an auto increment is easier. But, I always prefer to generate randomly for security reason.

Comment: @svgta Then why autoincrement is not secure?

Comment: It's depend on your case. For example, if you use id for a tracking url (without login of the user), everyone can see the tracking status of others : https://domain.tld/trackingStatus/order?id=1234. So, if the id is visible to the users, don't do auto increment

Comment: Most of the time, auto-incremented ids are perfectly fine. Just make sure to add security checks when needed (e.g. `view-bill.php?id=10` should check that bill 10 belongs to the logged-in user and not to someone else).

Comment: @svgta & Olivier: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you can, implement it using UUIDs. MySQL's UUID() function will return a 36 chars value which can be used for ID.

you can check here there have been the same discussion

[How to to create unique random integer ID for primary key for table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225793/how-to-to-create-unique-random-integer-id-for-primary-key-for-table)

Answer (score 0):

To add a complement of the answer of Amir, this is the code I use to generate a UUID code from PHP (found on stackoverflow) :

```
  function genUUID(){
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
      // 32 bits for "time_low"
      mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),

      // 16 bits for "time_mid"
      mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),

      // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
      // four most significant bits holds version number 4
      mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,

      // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
      // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
      // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
      mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,

      // 48 bits for "node"
      mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
  }
```

this is an example of what I get : 33aaf010-ca70-47fd-877c-00e09bc61697